# Php variable sending to js

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a problem to pass a var from php to js. BUT, I've already read all the related topics without finding any clue...
I've got a js script, which contains the part

```js
data: [
  { dt: '2009', value: 10 },
  { dt: '<?= $vstDate[0] ?>', value: 20 },
  { dt: '2009', value: 10 },
],
```

Then, what I'd like to do is adding a given number of vars, stored in a php array. I tried this, without getting it to work :

```js
data: [
  <?php
    for($i=0; $i<=count($vststats)-1; $i+=1) {
    echo json_encode("{ dt: ".$vststats[$i].", value: 5 },");
    }
  ?>
],
```

Please, how could I make it working ? All my thanks in advance !

Comment: did you read the json_encode documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

First make an array in php and in end pass array to **JSON_ENCODE**

```
//Array
$temp = array(array('dt'=>2009,'value'=>10), array('dt'=>2010,'value'=>10))

//json encode
echo json_encode($temp);
```